# Is there a way to exclude untagged artifacts from Harbor's immutability rules?

Tags: docker, harbor

I'm using a setting like this:

[image: screenshot of Harbor tag immutability rules dialog]

However, this also makes the untagged artifact immutable.

I want to delete untagged artifacts according to the retention policy, but I can't delete them because they become immutable.

Is there a good way?

Comment: This was supposedly a bug that was fixed in Harbor 2.5, based on this Github issue: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/issues/16335. I don't know what version you are using, but if you have the capability to upgrade your Harbor installation, you can try 2.5+.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the [`test_tag_immutability.py`](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/44f477e965e57ba619d494a7122c69a636906666/tests/apitests/python/test_tag_immutability.py) used by Harbor, and it does states that "excluding rule will not affect matching rule" (using the [`bmatcuk/doublestar` pattern](https://github.com/bmatcuk/doublestar#patterns=)).

In your case, since the [Tag immutability rule](https://goharbor.io/docs/2.4.0/working-with-projects/working-with-images/create-tag-immutability-rules/#create-a-tag-immutability-rule) mentions that "[y]ou can add a maximum of 15 immutability rules per project", you could try and add a tag *matching* rule, with an empty pattern  or `{}` (empty [sequence of characters](https://github.com/bmatcuk/doublestar#patterns=))
This might not be supported however.

The workaround would be to add an exclusion rule for tags named "`untagged`".

Any image tagged "`untagged`" (or latest) would therefore be candidate to deletion.

Comment: Thanks for checking, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to set an empty `{}` in the immutability rule, and an **image named "untagged"** is not the same as an **untagged image** which just shows up as blank (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jry2.png) and can't be matched by doublestar pattern. Furthermore, immutability rules take precedence over deletion rules: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/issues/10506#issuecomment-576010252. So, even if you manage to mark an untagged image for deletion, the immutability rules block it :(

Comment: @GinoMempin OK, thank you for the feedback. Hopefully, someone else will have a better option/solution.